# Nexus 7000 - switchport Voice configuration

Tags: voice, cisco-nexus

Nexus 7k
NXOS 6.2(8a)

I am trying to configure a voice vlan but the command does not seem available?

Is there something I am missing to enable that?

```
interface Ethernet4/1
  description AV_Hotline_501
  switchport
  switchport access vlan 501
  spanning-tree port-priority 128
  no shutdown

(config-if)# switchport ?
  <CR>       
  access     Set access mode characteristics of the interface
  autostate  Include or exclude this port from vlan link up calculation
  dot1q      Configure dot1q EtherType value
  host       Set port host
  mode       Enter the port mode
  monitor    Configures an interface as span-destination
  trunk      Configure trunking parameters on an interface
  vlan       Set VLAN translation mapping
```

Voice does not show up in switchport details

```
Name: Ethernet4/1
  Switchport: Enabled
  Switchport Monitor: Not enabled 
  Operational Mode: access
  Access Mode VLAN: 501 (AV_hotline_501)
  Trunking Native Mode VLAN: 1 (default)
  Trunking VLANs Allowed: 1-4094
  FabricPath Topology List Allowed: 0
  Pruning VLANs Enabled: 2-1001
  Administrative private-vlan primary host-association: none
  Administrative private-vlan secondary host-association: none
  Administrative private-vlan primary mapping: none
  Administrative private-vlan secondary mapping: none
  Administrative private-vlan trunk native VLAN: none
  Administrative private-vlan trunk encapsulation: dot1q
  Administrative private-vlan trunk normal VLANs: none
  Administrative private-vlan trunk private VLANs: none
  Operational private-vlan: none
```

Comment: What line card are you trying to configure this on?

Comment: F2E   -  N7K-F248XT-25E

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't been able to confirm this in any documentation yet, but I have looked for the "switchport voice" command on the copper ports on my own Nexus 7k and it is not an option for me either:

```
(config)# int eth4/14
(config-if)# switchport ?
  <CR>       
  access     Set access mode characteristics of the interface
  autostate  Include or exclude this port from vlan link up calculation
  dot1q      Configure dot1q EtherType value
  host       Set port host
  mode       Enter the port mode
  monitor    Configures an interface as span-destination
  trunk      Configure trunking parameters on an interface
  vlan       Set VLAN translation mapping
```

I can confirm that the command is available on a Nexus 2248TP connected back to one of my n5548's- I don't have a n7k-hosted n2k to test with. You're also not the only one who has [asked this question before](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/12030446/voice-vlan-nexus-7000) without a solid answer. Based on what I see here, and the understanding that when the Nexus 70xx's were designed they were built solely to be DC core/aggregation switches and weren't built to be as flexible architecturally as newer iterations of Nexus HW, I can only surmise that an access-layer feature like voice vlans was not built into Nexus 7k line cards. I wish I had a better answer for you, but since there doesn't seem to be any documentation publicly available to confirm this, I would suggest contacting your nearest Cisco SE if you have access to one and see if they can provide a better answer from the Nexus engineering teams.

Answer (score 3):

The Nexus 7000 was never intended to be an access layer switch, so they didn't include the voice vlan command.  However, you can accomplish the same thing with these commands (data vlan 100, voice vlan 200)

```
int eth 1/1
switchport mode trunk
switchport trunk native vlan 100
switchport trunk allowed vlan 100,200
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't address voice vlan discovery/configuration on the VoIP phone itself though.

Comment: That's true.  I'm more used to Avaya phone systems, which use a different mechanism for discovering the voice VLAN.